# list.files() in R and check which are different/new

Tags: r, difference

I am aware there is another question floating around with an answer to this, but I cannot find it.

I would like to `time_1 <- list.files()` in R, and later when I `time_2 <- list.files()` know which are new and which, if they were in there before, have been updated since `time_1`.

Does anyone know the name of this function or how to execute the task?

(Ultimately, I will be checking the timestamps of these files, but that is perhaps beyond this question.)

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Amazon Linux AMI 2016.09

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8   
 [6] LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8    LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] forecast_8.0      tidyr_0.6.1       highcharter_0.5.0 DT_0.2            dplyr_0.5.0       lubridate_1.6.0   jsonlite_1.3      shinythemes_1.1.1
 [9] ggthemes_3.4.0    ggfortify_0.4.1   ggplot2_2.2.1     shiny_1.0.1      

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.10      plyr_1.8.4        tseries_0.10-38   xts_0.9-7         tools_3.3.2       digest_0.6.12     tibble_1.3.0      gtable_0.2.0     
 [9] nlme_3.1-128      lattice_0.20-34   igraph_1.0.1      psych_1.7.3.21    DBI_0.6-1         yaml_2.1.14       parallel_3.3.2    gridExtra_2.2.1  
[17] stringr_1.2.0     htmlwidgets_0.8   lmtest_0.9-35     nnet_7.3-12       grid_3.3.2        data.table_1.10.4 R6_2.2.0          foreign_0.8-67   
[25] TTR_0.23-1        purrr_0.2.2       reshape2_1.4.2    magrittr_1.5      scales_0.4.1      htmltools_0.3.5   rlist_0.4.6.1     quantmod_0.4-7   
[33] assertthat_0.1    mnormt_1.5-5      timeDate_3012.100 mime_0.5          xtable_1.8-2      colorspace_1.3-2  fracdiff_1.4-2    httpuv_1.3.3     
[41] quadprog_1.5-5    stringi_1.1.3     lazyeval_0.2.0    munsell_0.4.3     broom_0.4.2       zoo_1.7-14       
> version
               _                           
platform       x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu     
arch           x86_64                      
os             linux-gnu                   
system         x86_64, linux-gnu           
status                                     
major          3                           
minor          3.2                         
year           2016                        
month          10                          
day            31                          
svn rev        71607                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)
nickname       Sincere Pumpkin Patch
```

Comment: `?changedFiles` seems to fit that bill. Otherwise, fiddle with `?file.info`.

Comment: yessir - that and `fileSnapshot()` want the points / answer @Frank?

Comment: Sure, might as well. I think there's no dupe since this search is blank: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Br%5D+changedfiles+is%3Aa

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The goal:

> I would like to `time_1 <- list.files()` in R, and later when I `time_2 <- list.files()` know which are new and which, if they were in there before, have been updated since `time_1`.

It looks like this is included in the base package utils. See `?fileSnapshot` and `?changedFiles`:

> The `fileSnapshot` function uses `list.files` to obtain a list of files, and depending on the `file.info`, `md5sum`, and `digest` arguments, records information about each file.
>
> The `changedFiles` function compares two snapshots.

Comment: This appears to be more powerful since it doesn't only check names but other file attributes as well.

Comment: Indeed, @42-, but see my answer as well; that timestamp component is ultimately very useful.  but much thanks to Frank for finding this for me.  Exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to Frank for pointing this out to me.  I wanted to provide a fully fleshed-out answer:

```
t1 <- fileSnapshot(timestamp = 'ts_stamps.txt')
t2 <- fileSnapshot(timestamp = 'ts_stamps.txt')
changedFiles(t1, t2, check.file.info = c("size", "isdir", "mode", "mtime"))$changes

               size  isdir mode mtime Newer
ev.csv        FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
nf.csv        FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
obs.csv       FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
ts_stamps.txt FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```